# Scrape Products from scrolling website using Python Selenium

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to scrape [THIS WALMART URL](https://super.walmart.com.mx/despensa/pan-y-tortillas-empacados/tostadas/_/N-1m4ynxm) using Python Selenium and PhantomJS. This website have finite scrolling, But I am not able to fetch all products URLs.
It look like this website is preventing my code to load other prodcuts

```
    def check_exists_by_xpath(xpath):
       try:
          browser.find_element_by_xpath(xpath)
       except NoSuchElementException:
          return False
       return True

    SCROLL_PAUSE_TIME = 0.5
     browser.execute_script("scrollToTopComponent.scrollTop = scrollToTopComponent.scrollHeight-(scrollToTopComponent.scrollHeight/2);")
     while not check_exists_by_xpath('//*[@id="scrollToTopComponent"]/section/div[1]/div[3]/div[2]/div/div/div[80]/h2'):
            # browser.save_screenshot(str(i)+".png")
            browser.execute_script(
                "scrollToTopComponent.scrollTop = scrollToTopComponent.scrollHeight;")
            if check_exists_by_xpath('//*[@id="root"]/div/div[2]/div/div/div/button[2]'):
                browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="root"]/div/div[2]/div/div/div/button[2]').click()

            time.sleep(SCROLL_PAUSE_TIME)
            new_height = browser.execute_script("return  scrollToTopComponent.scrollHeight;")
            i = i + 1
            # browser.save_screenshot(str(i) + ".png")
            print(new_height)

        print("broke")
```

Comment: Did you check if they provide an api,do the provide what you need ?

Comment: Yes they provide an API , but they are no longer accepting new registrations